# Breaking apart a large javascript application that uses the object namespacing pattern

Tags: design, architecture, javascript, application-design

I have a mission critical Backbone application built before AMD and CommonJS were widely used. This application makes heavy use of the Object Namespacing pattern, so that that all the views, controllers, etc. are nested deeply under a single ParentObject, e.g. `ParentObject.Views.Feature.TableView`. Continuing with this example, the `TableView` will reference other views, collections, utilities, etc. under the same ParentObject namespace: `ParentObject.Views.Feature.Table.Row`.

My question, I suppose, is it even possible to pull this apart and begin to use CommonJS, in large part to modernize the tooling around this application?

The application has 128,526 lines of code. What's the best I can hope for, here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like all things, it depends on how much time you have at your disposal.  If we're talking about breaking down the bigger pieces, you're looking at very little work, but obviously the smaller the pieces, the exponentially more daunting the task will be.

My advice would be to make small changes, taking components and putting them in their own modules, and then performing integration testing to ensure you haven't introduced any new bugs into your code.  This way you have the huge advantage that you can refactor until the last moment without having to perform last minute "gluegun and staples" patching of the code before sending it into production.